# How to Get SSIS Expression Leftover odd Rows right?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

[image]

I’m trying to come up with Expression in Conditional Split To Return Whatever leftOver Rows.

For example I have Flat File with 10 Rows and if want to split the file onto 2 Rows, I will have 5 files with 2 Rows in each file, but what if I want to split the file By 3 I will have only 3 files with 3 Rows each file, But Where is the Leftover 1 Row modulus remainder will go?. I tried the Conditional split and was fine But the LeftOver Rows Output DID NOT Come out Right. Please take look at my images and tell me if I have issues with my expression in Conditional Split and For Loop.

I have these variables:

1. `@Counter` = 0
2. `@ReCount` = total count that comes from RowCount Transformation
3. `@SplitRow` = Given Number that will Divided by
4. `@EndCount` = @ReCount / @SplitRow

I need to have Right expression for LeftOver or modulus remainder of any ‘Odds’ Number

Comment: This sounds like you should be using a Script Transformation with 2 buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already know the `rownumber` for each row as well as the `rowcount` of the entire file and the `split` number of rows in each destination file, the expression that will flag up any leftover rows from your splitting is any row in which the following returns true:

```
rownumber > (rowcount - (rowcount % split))
```